# Parse sign out function

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm attempting a simple sign out function where the view returns to my login/sign up view after the user signs out. I have tried using these two methods, but the application crashes every time.

First Method:

```
@IBAction func signPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! UIViewController
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Second Method:

I created the following function:

```
func loginSetup() {

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

            let vc = ViewController()
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

          }
}
```

then added it to my sign out function:

```
@IBAction func signPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()

    self.loginSetup()
}
```

both crashed and gave me an app delegate error.. whats the issue here?

here is screenshot of error given :

https://40.media.tumblr.com/1f044ecbdd5059836b0a360d16af9846/tumblr_nqzsobll0o1tupbydo1_1280.png

Comment: What's the error message then? Your info is not enough for us to help you.

Comment: This is not helping at all, are there anything printed on the console?

Comment: no there was nothing on the console, turns out the method was calling for the view controllers storyboard identity, not the name of the view itself. the targeted views identity was blank

Answer (score 0):

Providing you've set the root VC to the Login/Sign Up screen.

```
    func didTapSignOut(sender: AnyObject)
{
    PFUser.logOut()

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Then you can call this function in a UIButton IBAction but I call it on my UINavigationBar like so,

```
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSignOut:")
```

Comment: now the button does no function at all, like a button with no outlet

Comment: Make sure your outlets are all connected in the button's outlet tab and make sure in your code that there is a solid grey dot next to the UIButton action because you may need to reconnect it. There is no reason I can think of for this function to not work so check your please Action Outlets.

Comment: its all there i can't seem to figure out the issue

Comment: but i have my sign out button in a specific place on the view, not the navigation bar

Comment: Make sure your button is connected through an IBAction and not an IBOutlet and that it has a filled in grey dot beside the Action or Outlet call. I wasn't talking about the NavBar in my above comment.

Comment: turns out it was literally my view controllers storyboard identifier. it was blank. i thought the method just called for the identity of the actual controllers name

Comment: That would've been handy to check first